# Verify if the 15th line has the right string in it in Batch

Tags: string, search, variables, batch-file

the actual problem

I have a text file and i want to verify if the 15th line have the right string in it,
i could search the entire txt file but it would be slower.

for now ill be searching for the 1st line only because i know how to do it but if you know how to do it for the 15th

in text.txt :

```
zuluvictorcharlietango  
etc...  
etc...
```

code : lets say i wanna verify if charlie is somewhere in the first line of the txt file

```
set /p first<=text.txt
set list=alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot
setlocal 
for %%A in (%list%) DO (  
    ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>NUL
    findstr /m "%%A" %first%
    echo !errorlevel!
    if !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
        echo cool
    )
    echo uncool
)
endlocal
```

the problem is somewhere with the findstr and the variable first

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using a temporary file, you can replace your first line by the following:

```
more /e +14 text.txt >text.tmp
<text.tmp set /p fifteenth=
```

Comment: i finally went with
set /p firstline=<%1
echo. %firstline% > Searching  
because more /e is creating a too much of a big file and ask those who produce these txt files to put the string in the first line

Answer (score 2):

You may try this method:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=14 delims=" %%a in (text.txt) do set line15=%%a& goto continue
:continue
set list=alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot
for %%a in (%list%) do if not !line15:%%a=! == !line15! goto found
echo uncool
goto :eof
:found
echo cool
```

Comment: If the file is too large you may use `(for /L %%a in (1,1,15) do set /p line15=) < text.txt` instead of `for /f ...` and `:continue` to read the line 15, that may be a faster method depending on file size. You may test both methods and choose the faster one.

Answer (score 1):

`FINDSTR` expects a filename, not the contents of the file. Try the code below. I removed the `PING` command...wasn't sure why you wanted the delay.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET LIST=alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot
SETLOCAL
FOR %%A IN (%list%) DO (  
  FINDSTR /M "%%A" text.txt
  ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    ECHO cool
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO uncool
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

### EDIT 1

This code will find the 15th line for you.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET LINE=1
FOR /F %%i IN (text.txt) DO (
  IF !LINE! EQU 15 (
    ECHO %%i
  )
  SET /A LINE=LINE+1
)
```

Comment: ya that works but i wanted a faster search because my txt files are usually a few megs

Comment: @Spaceballs I'm not sure what you mean. What about your original code is faster?

Comment: well i just found a good answer imo...
create a temp.txt and put my 1st line in it and then search in the temp file instead of the original until someone finds a way to get the 15th line thanks anyway!

Comment: `FINDSTR` needs a file to look in...not a variable containing the contents.

Answer (score 0):

@Spaceballs this may not be simpler ,it is just a try

the first line of code creates a search file with line number(linenumber and : is appended

to the file and second line of code would give the 15th line in search file

the tokens=1,* delims=: is used to get the first token with delimiter and rest of the

line and %%k would give the rest of the line ignoring the first token which is the %%j

this logic is used to counter the files which are already having the ":" in them

The code below:-

```
findstr /n /v "mojofoko" search_file.txt > search_num.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%j in (`findstr /B "15:" search_num.txt`) 
Do @echo.%%k
@del search_num.txt
```